# Karma/Jasmine testing Ionic 6 - NullInjectorError: No provider for Geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic-native

I am receiving the following error when attempting to test with Ionic Native Geolocation as a dependency:

```
Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Geolocation -> Geolocation]:
          NullInjectorError: No provider for Geolocation!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'Geolocation', 'Geolocation' ] })
        NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Geolocation -> Geolocation]:
          NullInjectorError: No provider for Geolocation!
```

Here is what the test set up looks like:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule, IonItem, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FoloLocation } from '../models/folo-location';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component: HomePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;
  let platform: Platform;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomePage ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        Geolocation
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    platform = TestBed.inject(Platform);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
```

I have also tried providing a mock, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from this error:

```
Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Geolocation -> Geolocation]:
```

It seems that `Geolocation` depends on `Geolocation`.

Can you try doing the following:

```
providers: [
 { provide: Geolocation, useValue: {} }
],
```

We are giving an empty object for the `Geolocation` service. See if you see a different error now and if you do, you have to mock the public methods of `Geolocation` that you use.

Comment: The error remains when giving an empty object for `Geolocation`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.